# How can I optimize a big canvas animation

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I have a big canvas animation that I took from a codepen. The problem is it's running kind of slow at times. That is why I'm wondering how can I optimize this animation to make it run more smoothly? I would like as much tips as I can get and if you can change anything in the code to help me I would greatly appreciate it.

```
$(window).on("load", function() {
    (function() {
      var requestAnimationFrame =
        window.requestAnimationFrame ||
        window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
        window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
        window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
        function(callback) {
          window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
        };
      window.requestAnimationFrame = requestAnimationFrame;
    })();

    // Terrain stuff.
    var background = document.getElementById("bgCanvas"),
      bgCtx = background.getContext("2d"),
      width = 1920,
      height = 1080;

    if (height < 400) {
      height = 400;
    }

    background.width = width;
    background.height = height;

    function Terrain(options) {
      options = options || {};
      this.terrain = document.createElement("canvas");
      this.terCtx = this.terrain.getContext("2d");
      this.scrollDelay = options.scrollDelay || 90;
      this.lastScroll = new Date().getTime();

      this.terrain.width = width;
      this.terrain.height = height;
      this.fillStyle = options.fillStyle || "#191D4C";
      this.mHeight = options.mHeight || height;

      // generate
      this.points = [];

      var displacement = options.displacement || 140,
        power = Math.pow(2, Math.ceil(Math.log(width) / Math.log(2)));

      // set the start height and end height for the terrain
      this.points[0] = this.mHeight; //(this.mHeight - (Math.random() * this.mHeight / 2)) - displacement;
      this.points[power] = this.points[0];

      // create the rest of the points
      for (var i = 1; i < power; i *= 2) {
        for (var j = power / i / 2; j < power; j += power / i) {
          this.points[j] =
            (this.points[j - power / i / 2] + this.points[j + power / i / 2]) /
              2 +
            Math.floor(Math.random() * -displacement + displacement);
        }
        displacement *= 0.6;
      }

      document.body.appendChild(this.terrain);
    }

    Terrain.prototype.update = function() {
      // draw the terrain
      this.terCtx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
      this.terCtx.fillStyle = this.fillStyle;

      if (new Date().getTime() > this.lastScroll + this.scrollDelay) {
        this.lastScroll = new Date().getTime();
        this.points.push(this.points.shift());
      }

      this.terCtx.beginPath();
      for (var i = 0; i <= width; i++) {
        if (i === 0) {
          this.terCtx.moveTo(0, this.points[0]);
        } else if (this.points[i] !== undefined) {
          this.terCtx.lineTo(i, this.points[i]);
        }
      }

      this.terCtx.lineTo(width, this.terrain.height);
      this.terCtx.lineTo(0, this.terrain.height);
      this.terCtx.lineTo(0, this.points[0]);
      this.terCtx.fill();
    };

    // Second canvas used for the stars
    bgCtx.fillStyle = "#05004c";
    bgCtx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);

    // stars
    function Star(options) {
      this.size = Math.random() * 2;
      this.speed = Math.random() * 0.05;
      this.x = options.x;
      this.y = options.y;
    }

    Star.prototype.reset = function() {
      this.size = Math.random() * 2;
      this.speed = Math.random() * 0.05;
      this.x = width;
      this.y = Math.random() * height;
    };

    Star.prototype.update = function() {
      this.x -= this.speed;
      if (this.x < 0) {
        this.reset();
      } else {
        bgCtx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.size, this.size);
      }
    };

    function ShootingStar() {
      this.reset();
    }

    ShootingStar.prototype.reset = function() {
      this.x = Math.random() * width;
      this.y = 0;
      this.len = Math.random() * 80 + 10;
      this.speed = Math.random() * 10 + 6;
      this.size = Math.random() * 1 + 0.1;
      // this is used so the shooting stars arent constant
      this.waitTime = new Date().getTime() + Math.random() * 3000 + 500;
      this.active = false;
    };

    ShootingStar.prototype.update = function() {
      if (this.active) {
        this.x -= this.speed;
        this.y += this.speed;
        if (this.x < 0 || this.y >= height) {
          this.reset();
        } else {
          bgCtx.lineWidth = this.size;
          bgCtx.beginPath();
          bgCtx.moveTo(this.x, this.y);
          bgCtx.lineTo(this.x + this.len, this.y - this.len);
          bgCtx.stroke();
        }
      } else {
        if (this.waitTime < new Date().getTime()) {
          this.active = true;
        }
      }
    };

    var entities = [];

    // init the stars
    for (var i = 0; i < height; i++) {
      entities.push(
        new Star({
          x: Math.random() * width,
          y: Math.random() * height
        })
      );
    }

    // Add 2 shooting stars that just cycle.
    entities.push(new ShootingStar());
    entities.push(new ShootingStar());
    entities.push(new Terrain({ mHeight: height / 2 - 120 }));
    entities.push(
      new Terrain({
        displacement: 120,
        scrollDelay: 50,
        fillStyle: "rgb(17,20,40)",
        mHeight: height / 2 - 60
      })
    );
    entities.push(
      new Terrain({
        displacement: 100,
        scrollDelay: 20,
        fillStyle: "rgb(10,10,5)",
        mHeight: height / 2
      })
    );

    //animate background
    function animate() {
      bgCtx.fillStyle = "#110E19";
      bgCtx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
      bgCtx.fillStyle = "#ffffff";
      bgCtx.strokeStyle = "#ffffff";

      var entLen = entities.length;

      while (entLen--) {
        entities[entLen].update();
      }
      requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    }
    animate();
  });
```

EDIT: When I'm saying slow I mean the animation is choppy and not smooth

Comment: What do you mean by slow? Is your FPS poor or your code is taking time to render content. Can you add some more info on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @karthick, I mean that the animation is choppy and not smooth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it's your `Terrain#update`. Specifically your loop

```
    Terrain.prototype.update = function() {
      for (var i = 0; i <= width; i++) {
        if (i === 0) {
          this.terCtx.moveTo(0, this.points[0]);
        } else if (this.points[i] !== undefined) {
          this.terCtx.lineTo(i, this.points[i]);
        }
      }
```

You have `width = 1920`, so each `update` cycle is going to loop 1920 times, 60 cycles per second for 3 elements. 1920 * 60 * 3 = ~230,000 iterations per second. Try turning increasing the interval in your `for` loop and see if it helps

```
for (var i = 0; i <= width; i += 3) { // or maybe an even higher interval
```

EDIT:
After looking a little bit more, it appears you're painting 1000 `Star` objects on the screen as well. You might want to consider lowering that number. You're going to put everyone's computer on fire with this!

Comment: I have increased the interval which helped a lot, thank you. About the stars, I was thinking if it's possible to only place them only on the upper half of the canvas since half of it is obscured by the terrain. How would one go about doing that? That way things will look the same but with significantly less stars

Comment: Ohh I fixed that through simply halving the amount of stars produced on the Y axis. Thank you sir!

Comment: Always happy to help. Best of luck with the rest of your project